# How to use LambdaMetaFactory in REST API of Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, lambda-metafactory

I'm trying to use LambdaMetaFactory in a simple Springboot API as mentioned below. I'm trying to invoke both fetchUser and findUser methods of controller and service layer and fetch the execution time of these methods using LambdaMetaFactory.

**UserController:**

```
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/fetchUser")
    public String fetchUser(){
    return userService.findUser();
   }
```

**UserService:**

```
 public String findUser(){ 
    return userName = "XYZ";
   }
```

Can anyone please suggest me the usage of LambdaMetaFactory for each method invocation in Springboot API ? Is this possible ?

Comment: @Holger .. Can you please suggest me regarding this post and if possible .. can u please add a mock code ? Each HTTP request should call LambdaMetaFactory , get the instance and then call the corresponding method to fetch execution time.

Comment: Why do you want to use `LambdaMetaFactory` in the first place? Do you understand the purpose of LambdaMetaFactory? I suggest you ask about your original problem, regardless of specific implementation details (LambdaMetaFactory) that you think may be useful in solving the problem.

Comment: @apangin .. I have used AOP to log execution time, but it is creating performance overhead. So, thought of using LambdaMetaFactory to improve the performance and log the execution time

Comment: So, you actually want to log method execution time without high performance overhead, and that's what you should have asked about. `LambdaMetaFactory` has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Also, AOP does not "create performance overhead" per se. The way you use it can.